# Getting 'The procedure enrty point php_var_unserialized_init could not be located'

Tags: php, regex, windows, dll, solr

I am working on setting Solr for Windows for **Moodle 3.1**. My php info looks like **PHP 7.0.21** (cli) (built: Jul  5 2017 13:31:19) ( ZTS ) , and I am running Windows 10, 64 bit.

I have downloaded '7.0 Thread Safe (TS) x86' from https://pecl.php.net/package/solr/2.4.0/windows.

I have added '`extension=php_solr.dll`' to my php.ini @path C:\xampp\php:php.ini.
 When I place `php_solr.dll` from '7.0 Thread Safe (TS) x64' to  'C:\xampp\php\ext', I am getting

[image]