# 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_solr.dll' - The specified module could not be found.

Tags: php, windows, dll, solr

I am facing issue in using solr for global search in Moodle 3.1 . Main issue is [Getting 'The procedure enrty point php_var_unserialized_init could not be located'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293888/getting-the-procedure-enrty-point-php-var-unserialized-init-could-not-be-locate)

Now that dialog is not appearing, but when I do

```
C:\xampp\php>php --info
```

in cmd, I am getting

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_solr.dll' - The specified module could not be found. in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting 'The procedure enrty point php\_var\_unserialized\_init could not be located'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293888/getting-the-procedure-enrty-point-php-var-unserialized-init-could-not-be-locate)

Comment: How it is duplicate?.

Comment: Update your old question if you've progressed on the problem. This is the same issue, where you're probably loading a different .dll instead.